# MS Access 2010 How to use an SQL Where clause on column returned by VBA function

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access 2010 query

```
SELECT
    AirportName,
    EarthDistance(51.1480555555556,  0.190277777777778, Lat, Long, "K") AS Distance
FROM Airports;
```

it runs correctly, returning all the airports in the table and their distance from London Gatwick.

I can add a where clause such as

```
WHERE AirportName = "LaGuardia Airport"
```

and the query runs correctly. However, if I add a where clause such as

```
WHERE Distance < 5000
```

I get a dialog box asking me to enter the value of parameter Distance. How can I include this column in a where clause?

Comment: Column aliases cannot be referenced in the WHERE clause.  To resolve this, either 1) copy the entire expression in the WHERE clause, or 2) make the original query a nested query in which the column alias can then be referenced.

Comment: @CPerkins Is there any reason why you haven't posted this as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ms-Access: Concatenation, Create Alias, Use Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893917/ms-access-concatenation-create-alias-use-alias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you write the `SELECT` part of a query first, it is executed last. SQL first executes the `FROM` part, then the `WHERE` part to filter records, and finally it can `SELECT`. Therefore the aliases used in the `SELECT` part are not known to the `WHERE` part.

You can either repeat the expression in the `WHERE` part

```
SELECT
    AirportName,
    EarthDistance(51.1480555555556,  0.190277777777778, Lat, Long, "K") AS Distance
FROM Airports
WHERE EarthDistance(51.1480555555556,  0.190277777777778, Lat, Long, "K") < 5000;
```

or you can use a subquery as intermediate result

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT
         AirportName,
         EarthDistance(51.1480555555556,  0.190277777777778, Lat, Long, "K") AS Distance
     FROM Airports) X
WHERE X.Distance < 5000;
```

Comment: It's funny how your brain can work things out overnight. When I awoke I realised I could repeat the expression in the where clause. But I had not thought about using a subquery. If the computation is extensive, the second method might be preferable in this situation. Thank you for eplaining why I could not use the pseudo column name.